# Pinescript for Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Any idea how I can get the value of the previous Fridays High for the day?  I have this code which draws a line for the duration of Friday for the High, low and open prices of Friday, but I want to be able to extend that line to go across all the next week.  I am thinking if I can get the value of the Friday High I can then simply put - plot(*value of Friday high*, style=circles, linewidth=2, color=blue) and that would do the job.

This is the code I am using to plot the line at the moment

isFriday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == thursday ? 1 : 0
plot(isFriday() and highPrice ? highPrice:  na, title="Friday High", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)
plot(isFriday() and lowPrice  ? lowPrice :  na, title="Friday Low",  style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)
plot(isFriday() and openprice ? openprice :  na, title="Friday Open",  style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)

In the attached image, I have manually added the lines FO and FH to show the Friday Open and Friday High, I want them to plot like the blue line does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its surely possible.
once you have the value something like what you showed should work:
`plot(value of Friday high, style=circles, linewidth=2, color=blue)`

did you try it?
did it not work for you?
what's the plotting logic for your blue lines? maybe replicate it for your FO and FH lines.

its hard to give more advice without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is 1) how do I get that value and store it?  As I have not managed to store teh value I have not been able to try it.

The code for the blue line is a weekly value.  It seems weekly values will plot a line for the whole week but of course daily values only plot a line for a day.  This is the code that plots that line which is last weeks close value

WCLOSE = security(tickerid, 'W', close[1])
plot(WCLOSE, title="Last weeks Close", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=blue)